# How to configure logging for ASP.NET 5 running in Azure Web App

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to follow this link to set up logging for my ASP.NET 5 app in azure https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/logging.html but can't make it work.

What is the way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point Azure AppService doesn't support ASP.NET 5 standard trace logging. Here is a potential workaround:
https://github.com/davidebbo-test/ConsoleInterceptor

Answer (score 1):

You can configure logging through the Startup constructor. Here is a sample:

```
public Startup(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    var serilogLogger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .WriteTo
        .TextWriter(Console.Out)
#if DNX451
        .WriteTo.Elasticsearch()
#endif
        .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
        .CreateLogger();

    loggerFactory.MinimumLevel = LogLevel.Debug;
    loggerFactory.AddSerilog(serilogLogger);
}
```

That's all you need for configuration. From there, you can inject either [`ILoggerFactory`](https://github.com/tugberkugurlu/aspnet-5-samples/blob/6adaff568da705cc14c98b21f6465ca5ec4a2bc4/5-logging/server/RequestUrlLoggerMiddleware.cs#L13) or `ILogger<T>` (which is mostly the type for the class you want to inject the logger into) to the places you want to log stuff.

My sample configuration makes use of [`Serilog.Framework.Logging` version `1.0.0-rc1-final-10071`](https://github.com/tugberkugurlu/aspnet-5-samples/blob/6adaff568da705cc14c98b21f6465ca5ec4a2bc4/5-logging/server/project.json#L10). Also, [under `dnx451`](https://github.com/tugberkugurlu/aspnet-5-samples/blob/6adaff568da705cc14c98b21f6465ca5ec4a2bc4/5-logging/server/Startup.cs#L19), it will use [`Serilog.Sinks.ElasticSearch` version `2.0.60`](https://github.com/tugberkugurlu/aspnet-5-samples/blob/6adaff568da705cc14c98b21f6465ca5ec4a2bc4/5-logging/server/project.json#L16).

In Azure Web App, there is no difference the way you configure it. You just need to choose the right provider.

You can see the entire sample [here](https://github.com/tugberkugurlu/aspnet-5-samples/tree/6adaff568da705cc14c98b21f6465ca5ec4a2bc4/5-logging). Also check out [ASP.NET 5 and Log Correlation by Request Id](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/asp-net-5-and-log-correlation-by-request-id) which might give you some more ideas.

Comment: Thanks, My question was more specific to azure, ie writing to Azure Logs, table storage, etc

Comment: As I said, have a provider for that. Look at the logging repo to see if they have one today or see the other impls to implement it by yourself.

Comment: that was my question, "how can I log in azure?"

Comment: and that's what I am saying :) there is not concept of "Logging in Azure". You need to figure out where to log by yourself and look for a provider. If what you want is to log to Table Storage, you have several options today. Easiest is to work with serilog provider as I did above and use its Azure Table storage sink: https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-azuretablestorage this doesn't work on .NET core though.

Comment: By the way, seems like azuretablestorage sink doesn't work with sirilog rc1 at all

Comment: Simple trace logs should be work in Azure App Services. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio/
However, I suspect they don't support asp.net 5 yet